# What can be wrong in this entry existence check?

Tags: javascript

What could be wrong in my logic? 
It add the entries in any case if i check `(this.holdExists(x,y) != false)` or doesn't add at all from the start if i check `(this.holdExists(x,y) == true)`.

```
    //check if the hold with coordinates x,y already exists
    holdExists: function(x,y) {
        var precision = 0.01;
        holds.forEach(function(obj) {

            if ( (Math.abs(x - obj.x) < precision)
            || (Math.abs(y - obj.y) < precision) ) {
                console.log('Already exists!');
                return true
            } 
            return false
        });
    },

    // add hold by coordinates only
    addCoordHold: function(x,y) {
        if (this.holdExists(x,y) == true) {
            var h = Hold(x,y);
            holds.push(h);
            console.log('added\n', x,y);
        } else {
            console.log('A hold already exists!');
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning values from the iterator function you pass into `forEach`, but `forEach` doesn't care about those return values and they have nothing to do with the return value of your `holdExists` function, which as you've defined it is always `undefined`.

You may have meant:

```
holdExists: function(x,y) {
    var precision = 0.01;
    var rv = false;
    holds.some(function(obj) {

        if ( (Math.abs(x - obj.x) < precision)
        || (Math.abs(y - obj.y) < precision) ) {
            console.log('Already exists!');
            rv = true;
            return true;
        } 
    });
    return rv;
},
```

That does a couple of things:

1. It declares a variable, `rv`, to use as the return value of your `holdExists` function.
2. It switches from `forEach` to `some` so that you have a means of ending the iteration early (`forEach` will always loop through all elements).
3. It sets `rv` to `true` if it finds a match.
4. It stops the `some` loop if it finds a match.
5. It sets a return value for the `holdExists` function.

Comment: so its better just to use a simple loops `for/while`?

Comment: @NikTerentyev: Not necessarily, it's just a matter of knowing what you're dealing with and using it effectively.

Comment: @NikTerentyev - returning early when you're done with your work is one of the things that is easier with a `for` loop.  That's what I would use in this case since the purpose of `.forEach()` is to simplify your life and it's not really doing that here.  The `for` loop is also easier to step through in the debugger line by line.

Comment: @jfriend00: It's quite easy to step through a `some` loop. Just set a breakpoint on the first statement. (It *would* be nice if there were a debugger option for doing that automatically...)

Comment: Did you use `rv` for a (educational) purpose? You could directly return the result of `.some`.

Comment: @FelixKling: LOL, no, I just forgot about the return value of `some`. Good point. That said, your *second* point, that it may be clearer with `rv`, is also well-taken.

Comment: OK :) Personally I find `return holds.some(function(obj) { return (Math.abs(x - obj.x) < precision) || (Math.abs(y - obj.y) < precision); });` a lot nicer, but might be more difficult to understand for someone not familiar with `.some` and `.every`.

Comment: @FelixKling: Indeed. :-)

Comment: @FelixKling that's an amazing construction! Thanks, Felix!